# php code to echo all days between two dates

Tags: php

My form has two filters.

1) fromdate   2) todate

If user select FromDate = 01-05-2015 AND Todate = 31-05-2015 then it display all days between fromdate and todate in header.

**Expected output**

```
 Days - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
```

**My filter code to select fromdate and todate**

```
Fromdate : <input type="text"  name="fromdate" id="datepicker"></th>
todate : <input type="text"  name="todate" id="datepicker1">
```

**Display code to echo all days in column.**

```
<tr>
                    <th width="25%">Days</th>
            <?php for ($i = $fromdate; $i <= $todate; $i++)
            { ?>            
            <th width="26%"><?php echo date($i); ?></th>
                            <?php   }?> 
        </tr>
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: i need to display all days in a column between two selected date..

Comment: for ex if user select 01-05-2015 to 10-05-2015 and click submit then it display all days from 01-05 to 10-05 like   01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
<?php
$startdate = '2015/05/01'; 
$enddate = '2007/05/31'; 
$start = date('d', strtotime($startdate));
$end=date('d', strtotime($enddate));

for ($x = $start; $x <= $end; $x++) {
    echo "$x <br>";
} 

?>
```

Comment: yes this is working but i cannot understand how to get user selected value...you put hardcoded date in example...but i need this date to be selected from datepicker.......

Comment: i need this date from this datepicker....Fromdate : <input type="text"  name="fromdate" id="datepicker"></th>
todate : <input type="text"  name="todate" id="datepicker1">

Comment: $startdate=$_POST['fromdate'];